# search.com instead 404 on CentOS

Tags: centos

I have a CeontOS 5.6 box. When I `lynx sjdhfgjsdhfgs123123.com` (a non-existent domain) it opens search.com instead 404.
I thought this is because of the DNS servers used, so I tried it on a windows box with the same DNS servers, but I get 404 as expected on it.

How can I get rid of search.com on CentOS?

**Update**

Finally...
The problem was because of the missing `search` option in the resolv.conf file. Yes, faker suggested to add it, but the problem was that I restarted the network service after adding it and the DHCP client overwritten the resolv.conf file.
I think the `search` option is written in resov.conf file by default even if using dhcp client, but, apparently because of having multiple ethernet controllers and each controller having it's own dhcp client configuration it didn't add the 'search' option to resolv.conf.

I reconfigured now the dhcp client configuration to add `search` to resolv.conf and the domain resolving works as expected.

Thanks to faker. I wouldn't came to this result without him)

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use my ISP DNS servers or Google's(8.8.8.8). I get search.com for all non-existent domains. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: what does your /etc/resolv.conf contain exactly? See my (edited) answer.

Comment: Is the windows box on the same network and subsequent internet connection as the CentOS box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure this is not a CentOS problem.
On my CentOS 5.6 if I `dig sjdhfgjsdhfgs123123.com` I get NXDOMAIN reply back.

In any case, you shouldn't get a 404.
404 means that the server exists, is reachable but the page requested is not found.
You should get something like server not found.

And I'm highly suspecting your providers DNS being the cause.
Try a different DNS for a testing. Change /etc/resolv.conf - remove all othere DNS server and add 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 is a publicly available DNS server operated by google, I do not recommend using this one all the time but for testing it should be fine.

**-edit-**

Second idea:
What does your /etc/resolv.conf contain?
It could be that your search list contains "search.com", which would mean that if an application tries to resolve sjdhfgjsdhfgs123123.com it would also try sjdhfgjsdhfgs123123.com.search.com - and that would redirect you to search.com

**-edit-**

Third idea:
Add in your /etc/resolv.conf `search local` on top.
If you don't specify a search list, it will default to the domain part in which your host is.
If your host is `something.com` this would default to `com` in my understanding.
If you lookup `idontexistfjsdhfsd.com` it will also try `idontexistfjsdhfsd.com.com` and `com.com` again is a cnet domain which could redirect you somewhere.

Still this wouldn't explain why a `host idontexistfjsdhfsd.com` reports NXDOMAIN too - but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @faker: I think you mean `server not found` and not `page not found`.

Comment: @Khaled: You are right, edited the answer, thanks!

Comment: I already tried to use 8.8.8.8 with the same result. And 404 or Server not found.... yes, you are right. but the problem is that I get search.com for non-existend domains.

Comment: What output do you get from dig somefakedomain1877687.com and nslookup somefakedomain1877687.com and host somefakedomain1877687.com?

Comment: my /etc/resolv.conf contains just nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: dig somefakedomain1877687.com:`;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;somefakedomain1877687.com.     IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.                    501     IN      SOA     a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1308566066 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 63 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 20 13:41:44 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 116
`

Comment: `[root@in-md ~]# nslookup somefakedomain1877687.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find somefakedomain1877687.com: NXDOMAIN
`

Comment: `[root@in-md ~]# host somefakedomain1877687.com
Host somefakedomain1877687.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
`

Comment: Is there another place besides resolv.conf in CentOS where the problem could be?

Comment: ` ~]# ping somefakedomain1877687.com
PING phx1-ss-2-lb.cnet.com (64.30.224.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from phx1-ss-2-lb.cnet.com (64.30.224.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=236 time=185 ms
`

Comment: I have named running on the same box. Could it be because of named? (I run several test sites on this box, this is why I need named)

Comment: There is /etc/nsswitch.conf and of course /etc/hosts

Comment: Regarding named: no, it's not even used until you change resolve.conf to contain 127.0.0.1

Comment: This is silly, but is this only happening to .com domains? Have you tried somefakedomain1877687.net?

Comment: Indeed, this is not silly. For .net domains I get 404 Not found in lynx and Host Not Found when I try to ping them. For .org domains I get to com.org; and for .info I get to info.com. Can this info help somehow?

Comment: check my latest edit on my answer

Comment: With `search local` on top of resolv.conf it opens cnetnetworks.com for .com domains in lynx, but I get unknown host when trying to ping.

Comment: For .org domains still getting to org.com in lynx

Comment: @faker let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/572/discussion-between-johnz-and-faker)